# Problems w/ OpenJML Update Site

Tags: eclipse-plugin, jml

When I try to install the openJML plugin from the update site at http://jmlspecs.sourceforge.net/openjml-updatesite I get the following error:

```
An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=epp.package.java, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
Artifact not found: ... (with about 4 or 5 jars)
```

I've tried installing previous versions of the plugin, but all result in similar "Artifact not found" errors. Anyone have any idea why this isn't working? Or have a workaround I could use to get the Eclipse plugin to work?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bug report has already been opened, but no one seems to care (yet):
http://sourceforge.net/p/jmlspecs/bugs/397/

Seems that you have to compile your own version of it.

Comment: Thanks for checking this, I couldn't navigate the site very well; I was pretty much resigned to compiling it anyways.